# Which protocol for two servers where one is behind a firewall?

Tags: api, network-protocols, iot

There are two servers:

- **Local Server**

  - behind a firewall (DSL Router)
  - connected to microcontrollers (actors & sensors)
- **Cloud Server**

  - sends commands to Local Servers

The idea is that the Cloud Server sends commands to the Local Server. E.g. to trigger an actor. If there was no firewall, the best way would be IMHO to have a REST API on the Local Server. Unfortunately configuring a NAT is not an option.

What is the simplest and most common way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your other options are:

a) **pulling**, webrequest from local to online server.

b) **service bus**, also a pulling pattern but with a queue (i.e. Azure Service Bus or Event Hub in example)

c) **server of manufactor**, sometimes there is already a online service ready, like meethue-API for the hue Philips IoT Lamps

Let me know if you need more hint's.
Frank